# Android to execute web js

Tags: java, javascript, android, html

I am writing an app that can auto-login a website .There is a Javascript function which submit the form .I tested it by typing it in the Google Chrome Console ,and it worked .Can anyone tell me how can I do it in Java ?Please help me .Below is the form HTML Code :

```
<form target="_blank" method="POST" id="login_form2" action="https://webcat.hkpl.gov.hk/auth/login?wicket:interface=:0:loginPanel:loginForm::IFormSubmitListener::&amp;theme=WEB&amp;locale=zh_TW">
    <h4 class="orange">我的帳戶</h4>
    <label style="display:none" for="acc-box2">號碼</label>
    <input title="號碼" data-hint="號碼" class="text-field" name="username" type="password" style="display: none;" id="acc-box2">
    <input title="號碼" value="號碼" type="text" class="text-field" style="width: 150px; margin-bottom: 5px; display: block;">
    <label class="orange show_pass" for="show-check2"><input title="顯示" id="show-check2" type="checkbox" name="c2">顯示</label>
    <label style="display:none" for="pass-box2">網上密碼</label>
    <input value="004484284548649879936:lcyfpggwj-i" name="cx" type="hidden">
    <input value="UTF-8" name="ie" type="hidden">
    <input style="display: none;" class="text-field" name="password" type="password" id="pass-box2">
    <input style="width:150px;margin-bottom:5px;" class="text-field" type="text" value="網上密碼" title="網上密碼">
    <input type="submit" title="提交" style="display:none;">
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <a onclick="$('#login_form2').submit()" class="ac_login_btn" href="javascript:void(0)">
        <img height="32" width="94" title="登入" alt="登入" src="/common/tc/images/main_login_btn.png">
    </a>
    <div style="       vertical-align: top;       line-height: 1;       font-size: small;       padding-left: 100px;       color: #c63006;      ">請緊記在關閉瀏覽器視窗前，先要登出你的帳戶。</div>
</form>
```

The submiting function is $('#login_form2').submit() .
    Please help me .

Answer (score 0):

In java you can try this, if you want to login in from app to website

```
public static void loginToSite(HttpClient client, String username, String password){
List<NameValuePair> attributes = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
attributes .add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", username));
attributes .add(new BasicNameValuePair("pword", password));
attributes .add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "modifyPALS"));
attributes .add(new BasicNameValuePair("Submit", "Login"));

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost();

try{
    httpPost .setURI(new URI("https://webcat.hkpl.gov.hk/auth/login"));
    httpPost .setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(attributes ));
    client.execute(httpPost );
    AppStatus s = getSiteConnectionStatus(client, site);
}
catch (URISyntaxException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

but i am not sure if it's that what you want

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the whole project into java you will have to do it yourself. You should not expect anyone do this for you.

I could make suggestion so that you  avoid converting everything into java. You could use the Webview and load the html file in that webview. In this case you do not have to rewrite your form in java.